# Notes app Catalina and iOS 13 will not synch

Tags: macos, notes.app, catalina, ios

Notes.app in Catalina and iOS 13 will not synch reliably across devices. It seems worse:

- From the Mac. Changes on iPhone seem to more reliably appear in iCloud.com.
- Files with special characters. I use underscore to set the order and a folder called _FOCUS seems the be the least reliable.

It's a torment. I have over 1000 notes and rely heavily on the ability to edit from any device. Considering a third-party app :( .

Comment: I only have ~100 notes and I'm not seeing a problem with the sync.  I do notice that changes I make in Catalina take a bit longer to sync to my iOS devices than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: It's not working again :(. Changes made on Mac will NOT propagate no matter what I do. It's not a workeable solution to have to turn off and on synch of notes in iCloud as it takes some time to update, and unsure what happens to local changes. I do have other folders and files that begin with an underscore, I wonder if that's the issue.]

Removing the folder that started with an underscore, called "_FOCUS", seemed to fix the issue.

I couldn't just rename that folder. I had to create a new folder and move the contents.